# Question about convergence in probability (topic confusion)

Tags: probability, reference-request, convergence-divergence

I'm taking second year stats and was introduced the below concepts
[image]

For the third one, we use that to estimate the mean squared error in the case where the estimator is a nonlinear function of the sample mean. However, I can't find it anywhere in mathematical statistics textbooks (don't you hate it when that happens?). Where can I find out more about the above topics?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are asking for? Do you want a proof of the above properties, or only the third property, or...?

Comment: I would like to know what it's called so I can look it up in a reference book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept is called "[Convergence in Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability)".  Although for a sequence of numbers there's only one way of interpreting $x_n\to x$ as $n\to\infty$ for functions or random variables there are several different ideas about convergence.

If $X_n$ are random variables then $X_n$ converges to $x$ in probability if

$$\mathbb P\left[ \|X_n - x\| <\varepsilon\right] \to 1 \text{ as } n\to \infty$$for every $\varepsilon>0$.

This is quite close to the definition for real numbers, notice that it's not the same thing as $$\mathbb P\left[X_n\to x \text{ as } n\to\infty\right]=1$$

The second statement is much stronger and is known as "[Almost Sure Convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Almost_sure_convergence)". There are lots of other important ones. I mentioned almost sure convergence to try and convince you there's a point to having lots of different ones.  It's a good exercise to try and come up with an example of a sequence of random variables that converge in probability but not almost surely.

The results of your statements follow from the definition.

- Firstly if $\mathbb E(X_n)\equiv c$ and $\mathop{SD}(X_n)\to 0$ then by [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) we have $$\mathbb P\left[\|X_n - c\|>\varepsilon\right] \leq \frac{\mathop{SD}(X_n)}{\varepsilon^2} \to 0$$ as $n\to\infty$.
- Next if $\lim_{x\to c}g(x) = \ell$ then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $\|x-c\|<\delta\Rightarrow\|g(x)-\ell\|<\varepsilon$ hence
  $$
  \mathbb P\left[\left|g(X_n) - \ell\right| <\varepsilon\right] \geq 
  \mathbb P\left[\left|X_n - c\right| <\delta\right]\to 1
  $$as $n\to\infty$.
- The final statement follows directly from the second by noting that if $g$ is differentiable as $c$ then 
  $$\lim_{x\to c} \frac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c} =  g'(c).$$

Comment: Where is the last result from?

Comment: What do you mean by the last result?

Comment: Third statement in my original post.

Comment: @VanushVee I've edited to show you where the results come from. My undergraduate text books are all in storage so I can't give you a reference for this result, although it's probably somewhere in Ross.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/First-Course-Probability-Sheldon-Ross/dp/0136079091/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1372151166&sr=1-1